# Add an additional point to highcharts live data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts

Hi I need some help with adding an extra point series to highcharts. I have it updating live, but can only get one point to work correctly, but can get the second point to appear, but not with the correct value.

I have the below in a php file (dashchart.php):

```
//CREATE AN ARRAY AND ECHO AS JSON
    $ret = array($x, $y);
    $ret2 = array($x, $y1);
    echo json_encode($ret);
    echo json_encode($ret2);
```

$x is just a UNIX timestamp and $y is number.

Function to call the data, and then pass to highcharts to draw:

```
function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api_dashchart.php', 
            success: function(point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
                // add the point
                chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
                // add the point
                chart.series[1].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                // call it again after one second
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

I know it must be something really basic, but im just starting out with Javascript and can not figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try following code if `point` is of type json:

```
    var pointChart = new Array(point[0].xValue, point[0].yValue);
chart.series[0].addPoint(pointChart, true, shift);
```

If `point` is not json then accordingly give value of xValue and yValue of the point in the definition of pointChart.

Comment: Ok so now I have:
'success: function(point) {
     var series = chart.series[0],
     shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
     var pointChart = new Array(point[0].xValue, point[0].yValue);
     var pointChart = new Array(point[1].xValue, point[1].yValue);
     // add the point
     chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);
     // add the point
     chart.series[1].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);'

That doesnt seem to have worked.

Comment: You need to use "chart.series[0].addPoint(pointChart, true, shift);" and "xValue" in "point[0].xValue" it is meant to be the name of the parameter to be used as value in xAxis. Same for "yValue".

Answer (score 1):

hi i was looking at that and got the below solution

```
 $ret = array($x, $value1 , $value2);
```

and then

```
success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20
                 var series = chart.series[1],
                    shift = series.data.length > 20;


            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint([point[0], point[1]], true, shift);
            chart.series[1].addPoint([point[0], point[2]], true, shift);
```

and then

```
series: [{
                name: 'Point1',
                data: []
            }, {
                name: 'Point2',
                data: []
            }]
```